# Can I change default formatting for QDate::QString()?

Tags: qt, tostring, qdate

QT's QDate::toString() function, without parameters, converts a QDate to a QString with a default format of "ddd MMM d yyyy".  Our application is international and this fixed format does not reflect locale and regional settings.  I don't want to use LongFormat because it takes too much space; the default no-parameter is a more optimal length. I have obtained the LongFormat from system QLocale massaged the format string to give us a QString similar to the default format but also reflects international settings.

Is there any way I can tell QT to use my new formatting string whenever toString() is called so that I don't have to find all existing toString() calls and insert the formatting string as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Qt documentation of `QDate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html), you can specify the format you desire in [`QDate::toString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#toString-2).

Now, to avoid the repetitions that are bothering you, you can specify somewhere a `static` variable that contains the application formatting. Then you give it as parameter everytime you call `QDate::toString()`. This way, you will have to use always the same variable/format.

---

But if you really want to not give any parameters, the solution is to subclass `QDate` and redefine the `toString()` method by changing the default format by the one you want.

For example:

***.h*:**

```
class MyDate final : public QDate
{
    private:
        static QString my_format;

    public:
        MyDate();
        MyDate(int y, int m, int d);
        MyDate(const QDate & date);

        QString toFormattedString() const;
};
```

***.cpp*:**

```
QString MyDate::my_format = "yyyy - MMMM dddd dd"; // Specify the format you desire.

MyDate::MyDate() : QDate()
{}
MyDate::MyDate(int y, int m, int d) : QDate(y, m, d)
{}
MyDate::MyDate(const QDate & date) : QDate(date)
{}
QString MyDate::toFormattedString() const
{
    return toString(my_format);
}
```

And you can you it as follows (example):

```
MyDate md(QDate::currentDate());
qDebug() << md.toFormattedString();
```

Here I have named the method `toFormattedString()` in order to make the code more understandable. Feel free to adapt it as you want.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you.  I have already implemented the static variable approach.  Subclassing QDate had not occurred to me, and is an interesting approach.  I think the static variable approach will probably be best in our code base, so will use that.